# delete collection firebase in v9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

can some one explain how can i delete collection in firebase/firestore using v9 using reactjs

```
firestore()
  .collection('rate')
   .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.delete();
  });
```

this code i am using in v8 i need same thing in v9

```
 const q = query(collection(db, `${udata.id}`));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.data());
      
    });
```

already try this but this code only read data this can't allow me to delete so can some one tell me how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `deleteDoc()`, as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#deletedoc).

`deleteDoc()` takes a document reference, so you'll need to pass the reference from inside the forEach. In the forEach you're receiving a QueryDocumentSnapshot, so you just need to add a

```
deleteDoc(doc.ref);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a top-level function `deleteDoc()` to delete documents in using Modular SDK:

```
import { collection, query, getDocs, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const q = query(collection(db, `${udata.id}`));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    
const deleteOps = [];

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  deleteOps.push(deleteDoc(doc.ref));      
});

Promise.all(deleteOps).then(() => console.log('documents deleted'))
```